# Cannot recompile PHP on Mac OS X and enable PHP calendar

Tags: mac-osx, php-fpm, compilation

I compiled PHP 5.6.11. PHP-FPM to be more precise. It works find but I need to enable calendar. So I tried to to do:

> ./configure --enable-fpm --with-pdo-mysql --with-mcrypt --with-zlib
>   --with-openssl --with-curl --disable-posix-threads --enable-bcmath --enable-mbstring --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-sysvmsg --with-curlwrappers --enable-sockets --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-shmop --with-vpx-dir --with-mysqli --with-mysql --with-ttf --with-freetype-dir --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-t1lib --with-pear --enable-cgi --enable-xml --enable-libxml --enable-simplexml --with-iconv --enable-calendar --enable-dom

And then I did make and make install.

`Make` seems to be doing something but when I do `make install` I get this:

> Installing shared extensions:
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ Installing
>   PHP CLI binary:        /usr/local/bin/ Installing PHP CLI man page:
>   /usr/local/php/man/man1/ Installing PHP FPM binary:
>   /usr/local/sbin/ Installing PHP FPM config:        /usr/local/etc/
>   Installing PHP FPM man page:      /usr/local/php/man/man8/ Installing
>   PHP FPM status page:      /usr/local/php/php/fpm/ Installing PHP CGI
>   binary:        /usr/local/bin/ Installing PHP CGI man page:
>   /usr/local/php/man/man1/ Installing build environment:
>   /usr/local/lib/php/build/ Installing header files:
>   /usr/local/include/php/ Installing helper programs:
>   /usr/local/bin/   program: phpize   program: php-config Installing man
>   pages:             /usr/local/php/man/man1/   page: phpize.1   page:
>   php-config.1 Installing PEAR environment:      /usr/local/lib/php/
>   [PEAR] Archive_Tar    - already installed: 1.3.12 [PEAR]
>   Console_Getopt - already installed: 1.3.1 [PEAR] Structures_Graph-
>   already installed: 1.0.4 [PEAR] XML_Util       - already installed:
>   1.2.3 [PEAR] PEAR           - already installed: 1.9.5 Warning! a PEAR user config file already exists from a previous PEAR installation at
>   '/Users/jeannicolas/.pearrc'. You may probably want to remove it.
>   Wrote PEAR system config file at: /usr/local/etc/pear.conf You may
>   want to add: /usr/local/lib/php to your php.ini include_path
>   /Users/jeannicolas/src/php-5.6.11/build/shtool install -c
>   ext/phar/phar.phar /usr/local/bin ln -s -f phar.phar
>   /usr/local/bin/phar Installing PDO headers:
>   /usr/local/include/php/ext/pdo/

I tried to do `make clean` and `make install clean`. But still, after I compiled and check my PHP info I still could not see calendar enabled.

Is there another step that I skipped that I need to do to recompile my PHP-FPM on my Mac OS X?

My Mac OS X is Yosemite Version 10.10.3. I am using NGiNX as the server.